# Prove that $f(x)=x^3-9$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{31}$

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory

Prove that $f(x)=x^3-9$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{31}$.

**My attempt:**

$f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_{31}$ iff $f(x)$ does not have a root in $\mathbb{F}_{31}$.

So, I need to prove that $x^3-9\equiv 0\pmod{31}$ has no solutions. How do I do this?

Comment: A simple but tedious way is to just evaluate at all 31 values.

Comment: the cubes are a subgroup of the multiplicative group. Ten elements.

Comment: Yes, you could brute force it by plugging in $-15, -14, \dots -1, 0, 1, \dots 14, 15$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $p=31$ is a prime of the form $3k+1$, $a\in\mathbb{Z}/(31\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a cubic residue iff
$$ a^{\frac{p-1}{3}}\equiv 1\pmod{p}\tag{1} $$
It follows that it is enough to compute $9^{10}\pmod{31}$. Since $9^5\equiv 25\pmod{31}$, we have $9^{10}\equiv 5\not\equiv 1\pmod{31}$ and $x^3-9$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{31}$.